# SQL Server query to check if specific thing has been sold by person?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have issue of thinking query that would do following: show every person that has sold for example parts called `8888`, `7777`, `6666`, `3333`, `1111`.

I need to only see id, name and surname of person in result if they have sold these specific parts. Is this done by using / in some way at query?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide table names and table structures? Eg: `person` table, `sales` table?

Comment: _Is this done by using / in some way at query?_ - yes query will retrieve required fields

Comment: some sample data with expected output would help.

Comment: ALL the parts or just SOME of the parts?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The example query below should help.

Assuming `Person` table stores person records, and `Sales` table stores sales records.

The query below will fetch persons who have sold *any* of the `part_ids` specified.

```
select distinct p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
from person p
inner join sales s on s.sales_person_id = p.id
where s.part_id in (8888, 7777, 6666, 3333, 1111)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `subquery` instead of `inner join` that is better for performance and I prefer this code:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surename FROM Person AS p
    WHERE EXIST(
                        SELECT s.id FROM Sales AS s WHERE p.id=s.personID AND 
                                     Parts IN(8888, 7777, 6666, 3333, 1111)
               )
```

Comment: I don't think your claim about a subquery being faster is entirely true. It depends on the execution plan that is generated.. Also, if you're joining on indexed fields, join should win in my experience.  No matter how you write your query, SQL Server will always transform it before generating an execution plan. SQL Server might see that the inner join and the subquery are the same thing, so it might even generate the same execution plan.

Comment: Generally subquery is better, but it`s possible this is not true in every where

Comment: I'm honestly interested, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: As you said it depends execution plan

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is execution plan something i shouldnt worry unless database is very large? First time i learn about it and i have not used any official SQL databases just a few of my own and one for school projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare table @sales(part_id int)
insert into @sales values (8888), (7777), (6666), (3333), (1111)
declare @cnt int

select @cnt=count(*) from @sales

;With CTE as(
select sales_person_id,count(*)
from sales s 
inner join @sales ss on s.part_id=ss.part_id
--where s.part_id in (8888, 7777, 6666, 3333, 1111)
group by sales_person_id
having count(*)>@cnt
)

select p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
from person p
inner join CTE s on s.sales_person_id = p.id
```